# Power Query - M "Expression.Error: A cyclic reference" when merging with staging table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have two tables in my Power Query editor. `User` and `Account`.

I am trying to add a column to `User` that counts how many accounts are owned per user.

To do this I have a staging query called `UserAccountCount` that references Accounts and performs a group on the User Id. It returns a two column table with `User.Id` and `Count`.

I then try to merge and expand the `User` query on the `UserAccountCount` but it returns a `Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation.`.

I agree it is cyclical as I have referenced one query in the other. Is  there a way, besides duplication, that I can reference the queries.

I am trying to minimise duplicated code.

I tried to use Table.Buffer so that it would stop evaluating and possibly impact the order that the queries are run.

I should note that the `Account` table, joins and merges on the `User` table to bring in the `User.Name` before it is referenced by `UserAccountCount`.

Is it bad design to do this in a staging query. Should I just do this using an AddColumn formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add User.Name to your Group By in your UserAccountCount Query.

Then I would remove the Merge to the User table from the Account Query. You should then be able to expand both the User.Name and Count columns after the Merge with UserAccountCount.